# Agregar 00000 a una secuencia en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, apex

estoy creando una secuencia que inicie en 000001 para un campo de mi formulario, Pero cuando creo la secuencia no se agregan los 00000 que necesito solo el numero 1. Como hago para insertar estos ceros antes del numero y que se muestren asi en mi campo.

Este es el codigo de mi secuencia

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "NUM_DPCH_MP_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2 NOCACHE  ORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL
/
```

y este es el disparador:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "DPCH_MATERIA_PRIMA_T1" 
BEFORE
insert on "DPCH_MATERIA_PRIMA"
for each row
begin
:NEW.NUMERO := NUM_DPCH_MP_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
end;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "DPCH_MATERIA_PRIMA_T1" ENABLE
/
```

Por favor si me pueden ayudar, estoy aprendiendo sql y hay cosas que aun no manejo.

Comment: Creo que es mejor, que esos 0's los agregues cuando quieras mostrar el valor en algún sitio, no hace falta guardarlos en la BD. De hecho, solo se podría guardar en la BD si lo hicieras como texto, y evidentemente es mala idea.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví y como haria para agregarlos por ejemplo para mostrarlos en la columna de mi tabla?

Comment: Seguro que tienes alguna función que haga esto, quizás una que convierta números a strings, y le puedas indicar cuantos 0's a la izquierda quieres morstrar.

Comment: Te recomendaria mejor iniciar la serie en un número muy alto con muchos 0's. En varios proyectos he visto que los folios empeizan en numeros como 1000000001 Para resolver este problema.

Comment: Estaría gastando espacio inútilmente y el valor mostrado no va a coincidir con el almacenado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi asi.. (Por si alguien lo necesita)
En el disparador (trigger) se agrega la expresión Left Pad (LPAD) para  añadir ceros a la izquierda del número generado por la secuencia hasta que tenga una longitud de 6 caracteres.

```
BEFORE
insert on "DPCH_MATERIA_PRIMA"
for each row
begin
:NEW.NUMERO := LPAD(NUM_DPCH_MP_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 6, '0');
end;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "DPCH_MATERIA_PRIMA_T1" ENABLE
/
```

Comment: ok.. lo resolviste.. pero entendes que como idea es muy mala no? de paso, podrias explicar tu codigo? asi si otra persona quiere hacer algo similar (mala idea) lo puede replicar... gracias!

Comment: @gbianchi Si entendi todos los comentarios que hicieron, pero lamentablemente es algo que me estan pidiendo que haga asi, necesitan que se genere un numero correlativo que inicie en la serie 000001 y esta fue la forma que consegui para hacerlo.

Comment: ok.. agregale una explicacion a tu solucion por favor...

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ¿La columna `NUMERO` es `VARCHAR2`?. Dile a quien te lo pide que: 1) Es mas tardado comparar una cadena que un número. 2) Los problemas de presentación no deben resolverse en la persistencia. ¿Qué harán cuando por alguna razón se guardare el valor `'1E+05'` o  `'NULL'`?

Comment: Entiendo que el valor se guarda como texto, y no como número. Recuerda convertirlo a numero cada vez que debas realizar cualquier calculo, comparación, ordenamiento...etc